# how to fix Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\TasksController::store() must be an instance of App\Task, none given

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am going to scope Project model in My Task Model as following

```
public function scopeProject($query, $id)
{
    return $query->where('project_id', $id);
}
```

now I have following function in TaskController

```
public function store(Request $request, $id, Task $task)// this is line 45
{
    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign          = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority        = $request->input('status');
    $task->duedate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")));// $request->input('date');
    $task->project_id        = $id;

    $task->save();
}
```

I need save project_id in Task model according to the project tasks. but now i got this error:

> ErrorException in TasksController.php line 45:
>        Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\TasksController::store() must be an instance of App\Task, none given

what is this error and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: why do you pass this third parameter if you don't use it?

Comment: then how can I use this?

Comment: just remove parameter `$task`. You create an instance of Task with this line `$task = new Task;` and edit your route definition.

Comment: now occurred this error syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Remove `Task $task`, isn't it clear?

Comment: @Lilan maybe you forgot to delete comma after $id?

Comment: both your comments did well but above error has occured